# How do I connect one signal to multiple slots? Or if not possible, is there any workaround? PyQt, Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

I am writing my `pyqt` app and I struggle a lot because of one thing. I can not figure out how to connect one signal (pushbbutton clicked() or lineedit returnpressed()) to multiple slots (in fact only two ;p).

Here is my workaround code that let's say 'works' but it is not what i am looking for:

```
   self.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged(QString)"),self.workThread1.setValue)
   self.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.workThread1.toggle)
   self.connect(self.pushButton_3, SIGNAL("clicked()"), autotrace)
   self.connect(self.pushButton_3, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.workThread1.toggle)
```

I want that when I write some text in lineEdit and press ENTER it will trigger both self.workThread1.setValue AND self.workThread1.toggle functions.
The same with pushbutoon - single click initiating BOTH autotrace and self.workThread1.toggle functions.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about the code above? Why is it not what you are looking for?

Comment: Just write a wrapper that will be called when you press return, which will call both `self.workThread1.setValue` AND `self.workThread1.toggle` functions?

Comment: Because now i have to click the button twice to obtain the effect I want.
I am looking for something like:
'self.connect(self.pushButton_3, SIGNAL("clicked()"), autotrace, self.workThread1.toggle)' 
but it is not working ;(

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke There is no need for a wrapper. It is perfectly legal to connect one signal to multiple slots. *Devlige*, which PyQt version are you using?

Comment: @Andreas I am using PyQt4

Comment: @Devlige Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the behaviour. Connecting multiple slots to a signal has always worked correctly for me. As such, it is likely something else that is going wrong and the only way to debug that is with runnable code which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Devlige You might also consider using the [New-style Signal and Slot support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) introduced with PyQt 4.5. That makes connections much easier, IMHO, since you do not need to work out the correct signature string.

Comment: @Andreas perhaps, I use `wx` ;) That was just a workaround guaranteed to work, not an actual *answer*.

Comment: @three_pineapples Ok you are right. After trying this on a simpler code I found out that the mistake was in different place :) My problem was that I needed very small delay (time.sleep(0.01) was enough) between those two actions ;p THANK YOU